# Why do I get System.Web.WebPages.Deployment warning in my project?

Tags: .net, webforms

When I add a Web Control (.ascx) to my project, I get the following warning:

> C:\Projects\Figaro\BirdsOfPrey.ascx: ASP.NET runtime error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

It doesn't prevent anything from running and it doesn't seem to affect anything. But I would like to know what it means and why I am getting this error.

The project is an old school Web Forms project.

Comment: I had something like that recently and i think it had to do with temp files. You can try deleting the folders in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319` or `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` or possibly `C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root`, or try restarting iis and/or VS. i restarted vs because it had been open a long time, and the problem went away. Your mileage may vary, your msg is a little different.

Comment: Correction on the first 2 locations: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files` or `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`.

Comment: @wazz It ended up being something else.  A dependent project has a reference to a System.Web.WebPages.dll a different version than the parent version.   And System.Web.WebPages.dll has a reference to System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll.  So the problem was one level higher.  Oddly enough, everything works despite the warning.